# Remote python debugging from Intellij

Tags: python, intellij-idea, remote-debugging

The following instructions within a new `Run Configuration | Python Remote Debugging` point us to a `pycharm-debug.egg`:

[image]

But there are *no* `.egg` files anywhere in the Intellij installation.  So .. where to obtain the requisite files/.egg's to perform the debugging?

I am using `IJ Ultimate 2017.1.4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per stated [here (See section titled: Remote debug with a Python Debug Server)](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/remote-debugging.html#1) you can obtain it from the following directories:

- Windows: under the .IntelliJIDEAXXXX.X\config\plugins\python
  directory of the user home.
- *NIX: under the .IntelliJIDEAXXXX.X/config/plugins/python directory of the user home.
- macOS: under /Users/jetbrains/Library/Application
  Support/IntelliJIDEAXXXX.X/python/ directory